# Ubuntu Bluetooth Headphones Skipping

Tags: wireless, sound, bluetooth, headset

I have recently purchased some Bluetooth headphones and I thought the process would be fairly straight forward....boy was I wrong.
I have managed to use a workaround to get the headphones connected, however the audio is very unreliable and either skips all the time or has long pauses/delays.

I have read articles that state pulseaudio may have something to do with it, but I don't really know what that is.

Is there a way to solve this issue?
Thanks

Comment: This fixed this for me on 18.04: https://askubuntu.com/a/593849

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A2DP on PulseAudio - terrible choppy/skipping audio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475987/a2dp-on-pulseaudio-terrible-choppy-skipping-audio)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing this ppa:
https://launchpad.net/~eh5/+archive/ubuntu/pulseaudio-a2dp

and using apx or apxhd as codec

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Although I believe this is already a potentially helpful answer, I recommend that you **[edit]** it to explain how to do these things (or at least how to select a codec).