# Ubuntu 18.10 audio stopped working ("Dummy Output")

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Audio was working previously. In settings>sound, it shows "Dummy output".

No card is shown.

```
$ pacmd list-cards
0 card(s) available.
```

Although device is shown

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d71] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [103c:832b]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
```

No audio with headphone/earphone as well. It might be relevant that the problem occured when I was trying to fix bluetooth audio problem using this link -

[A2DP on PulseAudio - terrible choppy/skipping audio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475987/a2dp-on-pulseaudio-terrible-choppy-skipping-audio)

Although I edited /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf by appending 'options snd-hda-intel model=generic' at the end, I removed it afterwards but still the problem persisted. I don't know exactly what trigerred the problem.

Also, There is no option for audio devices in BIOS (My laptop model is HP 15bs180tx) as suggested by "Joel Kleier's" answer to -

["Dummy Output" No sound in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914463/dummy-output-no-sound-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out that the answer asking to enable audio from BIOS would've worked but **the option is not present in my laptop**. Also, the audio stopped working in windows as well (dual boot), so I **reset to setup defaults** (**not** the restore factory settings) and audio started working.

Also, for skipping audio problem, it occurs whenever WiFi and bluetooth both are working at same time, seems some kind of interference in both the signals. So, either **switch off WiFi while using bluetooth audio** or **first start bluetooth and connect to the device and then open WiFi to connect**.

Comment: You would've had a good answer if you had explained _how_ to do some of the things you mentioned. For ex, what is "I reset to setup defaults (not restore factory settings)" supposed to mean? Your wording suggests you were dealing with a cellphone, not a laptop, for example...

Comment: These are the options present in my BIOS menu, My device is a laptop, which is mentioned in the question itself.