# Linux Ubuntu 18.10 NO SOUND (Dummy Output)

Tags: 18.10, soundcard

I have "Dummy Output" in my sound settings. I am fairly new to Linux, however am fairly computer literate. I LOVE Linux, so I would really prefer a solution as opposed to going back to Windows which I hate.

My sound card is a HDA-Intel "Realtek ALC3235".

Also, I have a touch screen (which I don't really use, I use the keyboard) laptop and with one of the upgrades came the problem of the mouse jumping all over randomly while typing. Anyone have a solution for that?

Comment: Check `alsamixer` command in terminal and look there if the card is muted. With F6 there You can select sound card. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alsamixer . You can also check this for possible solutions : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto also please check this answer, maybe it will help in Your case: https://askubuntu.com/questions/914463/dummy-output-no-sound-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1111398/edit) with the output of `inxi -SA && hwinfo --sound`. Also take a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure), [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/948383/349837). Also can try to [reset UEFI/BIOS](https://askubuntu.com/a/1109087/349837) to default values.

Answer (score 2):

Found this bug listed https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1801538

I tested the following command and the result was instant. Everything fully restored.

```
systemctl stop timidity.service
```

Then went ahead and disabled. Will see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem after updating from 18.04 to 18.10. I tried restarting PulseAudio with

`killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*`

and

`pulseaudio -k`

but that didn't seem to do anything. I eventually started up the `pavucontrol` GUI, which I believe was also showing Dummy Output as the device on the first tab that opened up. However, I went to the "Configuration" tab and found that the "Profile:" drop-down for "Built-In Audio" was fully populated. (I don't entirely recall what it was initially showing. It could have been "Dummy Output", "None", "Off", or anything similar. The option disappeared after I picked a "real" device.)

For the way my laptop is set up, I went all the way to the top and picked "Analog Stereo Duplex" as the profile, which is probably what you want. There were also a whole bunch of HDMI output options for the video output on my laptop's mini USB-C dock.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to install a clean version of [Ubuntu 18.10](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). Remember to click on desktop version