# Bluetooth Headphones with choppy audio

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones

I recently bought a Jabra Elite 75t to connect to my computer. I did the following:

1. Entered Pair Mode with my headphones
2. Opened Settings -> Bluetooth
3. Clicked on "Jabra Elite 75t" to pair the device
4. Device was paired

When listening to youtube I intermittently get choppy audio with this device. I never experienced this with a wired setup before.

I tried the following fixes but nothing has worked; there is still some choppiness to it:

- [A2DP on PulseAudio - terrible choppy/skipping audio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475987/a2dp-on-pulseaudio-terrible-choppy-skipping-audio)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/Jabra/comments/j5489d/if_you_use_jabra_earbuds_with_linux_you_need_to/

The headphones seem to work fine on my Android phone, so I'm not sure what the issue is with Ubuntu (I'm on 20.04). This is the output from running `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` on my terminal:

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:9df0] (rev 30)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:0034]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 3.1 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1532:0239 Razer USA, Ltd Razer Blade
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:56d5 IMC Networks Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 9636:9311  
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 046d:c336 Logitech, Inc. 4-Port USB 2.1 Hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1a40:0801 Terminus Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 2.1 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Anything I'm doing wrong or advice on how to solve this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: which media player you are using ? if vlc. please try a different media player like :- firefox, chrome, parole media player .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N"
```

and reboot.

That should fix BT and 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi problem.

Comment: Yes it seems to have worked with very few problems so far! Thank you very much. Can I ask what exactly this fixes?

Comment: This command disables BT-Wi-Fi coexistence algorithm that doesn't work well with some Intel devices.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is probably related to the first answer in this thread. After trying a couple of configurations I found on the net, nothing worked for me.  Then I thought maybe my WiFi signal is clashing with the Bluetooth signal, and voila - it worked.

Just switch off your WiFi adapter and it should work. However, if you need to use your WiFi then I suspect the problem is actually with network discovery feature. If you can somehow kill this feature and connect directly to known networks, the Bluetooth should work.

Comment: If both frequencies are provided, pinning your wifi to 5.5GHz solves the problem as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Really simple solution to try:

`bluetoothctl scan off`

This stops the adapter from scanning for more devices. Especially in bluetooth-busy areas this can overwhelm the adapter.

If the Bluetooth window is open this means it's scanning for devices. Closing the bluetooth connection window can be equivalent to `bluetoothctl scan off` depending on your distro. It is on Fedora 35.