# how to force SBC codec on A2DP profile on ubuntu 22.04 bluetooth audio?

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, pulseaudio

[image]

my headphones always chop audio when reconnecting. and always work normally on the first pairing connection. i've tested this several times. i've tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1207648/411689) but it didn't work. using `pavucontrol`, i noticed all reconnections use `A2DP` with `SBC XQ 552kbps` (choppy audio) and all pairing connections use `A2DP` with `SBC` (normal audio). switching the codecs i discovered the only one with good audio is `SBC`. i've found `Supported audio codec: SBC` on the headphone manual (philips TAT2206).

how can i configure my bluetooth settings to always use `SBC` codec instead of any other when my headphones reconnects?

Comment: same problem here in 22.04 with PulseAudio. When connection initiated from PC, codec is always `sbc_xq_552` with choppy audio, but when initiated from the headphone, is `sbc`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The only solution that worked was upgrading to U 22.10. U 22.10 uses pipewire instead for pulseaudio for audio.

Comment: No need to upgrade to use pipewire it can be installed on Ubuntu 22.04