# Connecting bluetooth mouse causes bluetooth audio malfunction

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, mouse

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, on a Lenovo ThinkPad t460s. I am apparently using pulse audio and blueman is installed.
The issue is that if I am listening to anything on a pair of Sony LinkBuds S everything is fine until I connect a Logitech MX Master 3 via bluetooth. At that point audio quality drops and it starts stuttering.
I've tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475987/a2dp-on-pulseaudio-terrible-choppy-skipping-audio) without success.

Answer (score 0):

After a while I came up with the idea that the high quality LDAC codec from Sony might be the problem. I used the pulseaudio volume module to edit the codec used for the connection (attached picture, in Italian). SBC codec works just fine.

pulseaudio volume module window:

[image: pulseaudio volume module window]