# Bluetooth earbuds not connecting, wifi disconnecting, choppy audio

Tags: networking, sound, bluetooth

Two days ago, I bought a pair of Jabra Elite 8 Active bluetooth earbuds. I've had to spend these past 2 days troubleshooting to get my headset to properly work with my laptop running ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.

I tried out some suggestions in this forum, and for now it seems that I have managed to get it working. I am posting this to share what problems I faced and what solution worked for me in the hopes it will be useful for someone else.

Out of curiosity, I'd also like to understand more why I had these problems and why these solutions worked. Perhaps someone here can offer me an explanation.

1. In the beginning, I could not pair the earbuds with my laptop through the usual method using the Bluetooth menu in Settings. The earbuds stays 'Not Set Up'. This was solved by installing blueman and pairing with the earbuds through bluetooth manager. Question is, what does blueman do differently than the Bluetooth menu in Settings that made this work?
2. Once I had the earbuds connected, I tried streaming music through spotify. The audio I got from my earbuds were extremely choppy and my wifi connection kept disconnecting for some reason. Through trial and error, I found that the wifi connection kept disconnecting only when I had my earbuds connected. Otherwise, it was fine. I 'solved' this by using a usb wifi dongle I borrowed from a friend to connect to my wifi. My question is, why are my earbuds interfering with the wifi connection? Also, I was wondering whether there was an alternative solution to this without needing a wifi dongle? If not, should I buy a wifi dongle or a bluetooth dongle instead?
3. Regarding the choppy audio, I followed this [suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475987/a2dp-on-pulseaudio-terrible-choppy-skipping-audio) and it seems to help. I still get choppy audio sometimes, but way less than I used to. I'm still experimenting with the latency.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ask Ubuntu is a Q&A site. You need to change your post to be in the form of a question which you are then quite at liberty to answer yourself.